# Submit data from a form wordpress theme to other site

Tags: wordpress

Supposed I have a website that run on wordpress and it has a form which use to collect user's information (e.g., Checkout function) and the data will be submitted to other site that need it.

Is there a better way of doing that in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. This can be done using API services.

Comment: Is there any documentation you can suggest?

Comment: Check this .. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-post-data-to-another-website-using-script/4390